# How can I find the monodromy of a cyclic galois cover of the affine line minus a few points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, galois-theory, covering-spaces

Consider the following cyclic covering of the affine line minus a few points:
$$
\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[t,x]/(x^n - t(t-1)(t-2))) \to \mathbb{A}^1_t - \{ 0, 1, 2 \}
$$
How can I find the local monodromy representations around one of these points of degeneracy?